# Logging performance counters to ODBC in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, performance-counters

I'm trying to update a data collector set to log specific performance counters to ODBC (SQLServer), however the "Data source name" dropdown is greyed.

I have configured an ODBC System data source (from both 32 and 64 bit ODBC).

[image]

Comment: Seemed to be pretty easy for this guy: http://blog.datacenterfromhell.net/2013/06/collecting-microsoft-performance.html
What is he doing differently than you?

Comment: I didn't have this problem when I set it up on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The log format must be set to SQL, not Binary
- The ODBC data source must be a 64-bit System DSN (32-bit DSNs does not appear in list)

[image]

Thanks to Ryan - the detail was in the blog post.